# percentileofscore groupby expanding

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to calculate the following:

1. Compute the percentile rank of a value relative to a list of values
   in a different series.
2. By group.
3. And in an expanding `dataframe` window.

I've tried the following without success.

```
df['pct']=df.groupby(['Category']).expanding(1).apply(lambda x: stats.percentileofscore(df['values'],1)).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the following link for your question. :  [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The original question did not include an example, so I've made a simple one myself.

The issue comes down to your use of `.apply(lambda x: ...)`. When you use this notation, you define a lambda function that says for every input x, we should do what with x. However, in your original version, you never define x in your lambda function. See below for the fix.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import percentileofscore

# example I have constructed
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['alex', 'alex', 'bob', 'alex', 'bob', 'alex', 'bob', 'bob'],
        [0, 3, 10, 1, 15, 6, 12, 18]              
    ]).T
df.columns = ['Category', 'values']

# suggested fix
df['pct'] = df.groupby(['Category']).\
                expanding(1).\
                apply(lambda x: percentileofscore(x,1)).\ 
                reset_index(0, drop=True)
```